# Can't Move the Gizmo - Just Draws a Select Box

Tags: versions, select, gizmo

In previous versions of Blender, I was able to click on the different points of a 3D gizmo to manipulate it.

However, after the 3.4 update this no longer works. It just draws a select box. I wondered if it was just a bug for me for that engine, but having installed 3.5 I see it's the same.

https://youtu.be/r9QZdI0dnqk <-- now working!

I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried resetting the keymap and it doesn't fix it.

[image]

I've tried the different Drag modes: select box, active tool, tweak. It's the same in Object and Edit mode.

---

Edit: https://youtu.be/fdU6jfdY2OU

Restoring factory setting fixes it, but the issue resets when Blender is opened again.

I suspected it'd messed something up with my custom keymap, but even with the default keymap it doesn't work. The above video is using only Blender's default keymap. What *is* going on?

---

SOLVED:

I went into the AppData 'config' folder for 3.5 and copy-pasted everything from 3.3 into it. Apparently reloading factory settings and changing the keybinds wasn't successfully saving to the config or something.

Comment: It's the gizmo on the cube that you're trying to move? Drawing the select box just means that you're in Box select mode which I think is the default. You should be able to simply drag any of the 3 arrows or the white circle to move the cube around. What icon is selected if you press 'T' to bring up the toolbar? - Should be the Move icon (4 arrows). Can you move the cube with the 'G' key as usual?

Comment: Hi, I've changed the YouTube video to one that works, you can see the exact nature of the problem. I've tried select box, active tool and tweak and it's the same. The hotkeys work as normal. I'm experienced in Blender but havn't had this issue before and can't find a setting to fix it. @JohnEason

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. It works the same in all 4 versions that I have installed here. Unless anyone else here has an answer I'd try using File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings but you'll lose any other settings that you have set up of course.

Comment: I followed your advice and reloaded factory settings; then just put back all my other settings. It works now, guess it's just a ghost in the machine.

Comment: Cosmic rays! :^) You'll have to do the same with the other version if you still want to use both 3.4.1 and 3.5.

Comment: Sooo, restarting Blender breaks it again. Added extra details to the post. I think I'll report this as a bug.

Comment: You've never actually said what operating system you're using, but since no-one else seems to have had the same problem as you it's got to be something to do with your machine not Blender itself.